# Cast uint value to list with names by enum

Tags: c#, enums, casting

I have an enum

```
enum e : uint
        {
            a = 0x00000001,
            b = 0x00000002,                
            c = 0x00001000,
            d = 0x00002000
        }
```

and `uint v = 0x00003003`.
How to convert 0x00003003 to string list like `{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}` ?

I tried

```
Console.WriteLine(Enum.ToObject(typeof(e), v));
```

but it prints nothing.

Comment: I think you'd have to write some additional code with bit-operations. I doubt that this is supported like this.

Comment: In addition, looking at the values, this enum doesn't appear to **Flags** (bits are not mutually exclusive), so there could be multiple combinations that sum up to create the same `uint`, hence any such function cannot work.

Comment: string results = string.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, 32).Where(x => (((1 << x) & v) > 0)).Select(x => ((e)(1 << x)).ToString()));

Comment: dotNET, `[Flags]` solved the issue. Can you please create answer for the question? I'll mark it as correct answer. Thank you a lot!